# Looking for a way to read and write a text file

Tags: c#

I am making a program and I have absolutely no clue how to read and write a text file. I would like it so that I only need one text file that has all kinds of data, so I need to be able to read specific lines of the file.

Comment: Check this out: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816149

Comment: Next time, try use google "read and write a text file in C#" (your title) before ask. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("YourFile.txt"))
{
  String line = sr.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` classes:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Sample.txt");

var data = sr.ReadLine();


StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Test.txt");

sw.WriteLine("Hello World!!");
```

Taken from: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816149.

EDIT: To clarify, **always** close the streams. `sr.Close()` `sw.Close()`. Or wrap them within a `using` statement just as James did on his answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the File class.
`string h1 = File.ReadAllText("D:\\TempFiles\\h1.txt");
string h1 = File.WriteAllText("D:\\TempFiles\\h1.txt");`